# Document library event receiver when creating documents

Tags: document-library, event-handlers

I created an event receiver that processes some information in docx files when uploaded to the library. I do this in ItemAdded event. Everything works fine when the file is uploaded. When the files are created by clicking the New Document icon on the ribbon and the file is saved to the library, event receiver code is not fired.

Is there any other event that I should be handling?

Comment: Is the event totally not firing? I assume you've had a debugger attached and walked through the behaviour? My first instinct would be that ItemAdded is fired earlier than expected and the data you're expecting isn't there so an exception is getting thrown silently in the background. Try looking at the ItemUpdated event too.